# PHP preg_replace all commas inside brackets and square bracket

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking to replace all commas that exist within a bracket or square bracket using preg_replace.

I am able to replace all commas inside brackets using the below:

```
$clean_ingredients = preg_replace('/(\([^)]*),([^)]*\))/', '$1! $2', $ingredients );
```

This results with commas inside brackets being replaced but I can't work out how to also check for commas inside square brackets.

What I would like to achieve is:

```
$ingredients = "Skim Milk Powder, Condensed Milk, Coconut Cream, Strawberry Jam [Cane Sugar, Strawberries (40%), Gelling Agent (Fruit Pectin), Acidity Regulator (330)], Hazelnuts, Barley Malt Extract, Emulsifier (Soya Lecithin), Peppermint [Vegetable Oil, Peppermint Oil, Antioxidant (Mixed Tocopherols Concentrate)], Salt, Citric Acid, Flavouring (Vanillin), Vanilla, Colouring (E102, E133, E129, E132, E171, E122, E124, E110, E172, E153).";

$clean_ingredients = preg_replace('????', '$1! $2', $ingredients );

echo $clean_ingredients; 

// Output: Skim Milk Powder, Condensed Milk, Coconut Cream, Strawberry Jam [Cane Sugar! Strawberries (40%)! Gelling Agent (Fruit Pectin)! Acidity Regulator (330)], Hazelnuts, Barley Malt Extract, Emulsifier (Soya Lecithin), Peppermint [Vegetable Oil! Peppermint Oil! Antioxidant (Mixed Tocopherols Concentrate)], Salt, Citric Acid, Flavouring (Vanillin), Vanilla, Colouring (E102! E133! E129! E132! E171! E122! E124! E110! E172! E153).
```

Is there any regex experts out there that know what could achieve what I'm after?

Comment: How about extracting the parenthesized part, split it by `,` and then join with `!`?

Comment: If the parentheses and brackets are balanced and the parenthetical and  bracketed clauses are not nested you could replace matches of `,(?=[^[]*]|[^(]*\))` with `'!'`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZkFHS5/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
<?php

$ingredients = "aaa (1,2,3) bbb [4,5,6,7]";
$clean_ingredients = preg_replace_callback('/\([^()]*\)|\[[^][]*]/', function($m) {return str_replace(',', '! ', $m[0]);}, $ingredients );
echo $clean_ingredients;
// => aaa (1! 2! 3) bbb [4! 5! 6! 7]
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/T5VDs) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aivrHK/1).

The `\([^()]*\)|\[[^][]*]` regex matches

- `\([^()]*\)` - a `(` char + zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` + a `)` char
- `|`  - or
- `\[[^][]*]` - a `[` char + zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` + a `]` char.

The function inside `preg_replace_callback` replaces all commas with `!` + space.

Comment: In `{return str_replace(',', '! ', $m[0]);}` remove the space at the end of `! `.

Comment: Works like a dream for my scenario. Thanks!

Comment: @l'L'l The space is not mine, it is there in the OP replacement string, see `$1! $2`. If OP needs it, I can't simply omit it in the answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: There was extra space after each word of the resulting replacement string containing "!" at the end; when omitting the space in the regex replacement the output looked exactly like the OP desired. (eg. `E102!  E133!  E129!` vs `E102! E133! E129!`)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I see where the issue is; in your example you have `(1,2,3...)` whereas the OP has `(1, 2, 3...)`, and why the extra spaces.

Comment: In that case, I'd just replace `str_replace(',', '! ', $m[0])` with `preg_replace('~,\s*~', '! ', $m[0])` to enforce a single space after `!`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ingredients = "Skim Milk Powder, Condensed Milk, Coconut Cream, Strawberry Jam [Cane Sugar, Strawberries (40%), Gelling Agent (Fruit Pectin), Acidity Regulator (330)], Hazelnuts, Barley Malt Extract, Emulsifier (Soya Lecithin), Peppermint [Vegetable Oil, Peppermint Oil, Antioxidant (Mixed Tocopherols Concentrate)], Salt, Citric Acid, Flavouring (Vanillin), Vanilla, Colouring (E102, E133, E129, E132, E171, E122, E124, E110, E172, E153).";

echo preg_replace_callback('~\[[^]]+|\([^)]+~', fn($m) => strtr($m[0], ',', '!'), $ingredients);
```